# Count rows (conditionally) within specified time period by group in R

Tags: r, datetime, count, data-wrangling, multiple-users

I am working with user generated data and I want to count the number of rows/activities i.e. Calls by each user made within a specific time period. Here is a mock dataframe, similar to what I am working with:

```
library(ids)#for generating the UserID variable
library(wakefield)#for generating the Status variable
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)
UserID<-random_id(n=10, bytes = 5)
DateTime<-seq.POSIXt(from = as.POSIXct("2020-08-01 01:00:00", tz = Sys.timezone()), length.out = 70, by = "15 mins")
df<-cbind(UserID,DateTime)
df<-as.data.frame(df)
df$Status<-r_sample_factor(x = c("Answered", "Abandoned", "Engaged"), n=70)
df$DateTime<-seq.POSIXt(from = as.POSIXct("2020-08-01 01:00:00", tz = Sys.timezone()), 
                        length.out = 70, by = "15 mins")#re-doing this again as it annoyingly converts to numeric each time 

df<-df%>%arrange(UserID,DateTime)
head(df)


      #UserID            DateTime    Status
#1 0a5f3a2a8b 2020-08-01 02:00:00   Engaged
#2 0a5f3a2a8b 2020-08-01 04:30:00   Engaged
#3 0a5f3a2a8b 2020-08-01 07:00:00   Engaged
#4 0a5f3a2a8b 2020-08-01 09:30:00   Engaged
#5 0a5f3a2a8b 2020-08-01 12:00:00   Engaged
#6 0a5f3a2a8b 2020-08-01 14:30:00 Abandoned
```

What I want to do is count the number of Calls by `UserID` within a 5 hour period, with two other conditions:-

1. If there isn't another Call within the 5 hour period of the last Call that the User made, then this goes down as a single "attempt"
2. If the user has N Calls within a 5-hour period until they get "Answered", then that counts as an "successful" attempt. Otherwise, it goes down as an "unsuccessful"

Here is what I am trying to achieve:-

```
UserId          OrigTime       LastTime          Calls  Status       Successful
0a5f3a2a8b  2020-08-01 02:00:00 2020-08-01 07:00:00 3   Engaged          No
16db61d2bc  2020-08-01 03:15:00 2020-08-01 03:15:00 1   Answered         Yes
6355f7700d  2020-08-01 01:00:00 2020-08-01 06:00:00 3   Answered         Yes
9b9fab9789  2020-08-01 04:15:00 2020-08-01 09:15:00 3   Answered         Yes
...
```

So `OrigTime` is the time of their first call within a single attempt, and `LastTime` is the time of their last call within the same single attempt. The `Calls` column counts the number of calls the User made within that attempt, `Status` is the status of the last call within an attempt and "Successful" can be logical, saying whether the last call within that attempt was answered or not.

Any pointers in the right direction would be great. I imagine that there is some `data.table` or `dplyr` solution but I haven't done much of this kind of activity before, so not sure where to begin. Big thank you in advance :)

***EDIT***

@Waldi provided a solution which provided nearly what I needed. Here is the solution that works best so far (slightly amended from @Waldi 's answer):-

```
CondCount <- function(data,maxdelay){
  result <- list()
  row <- 0
  calls <- 0
  OrigTime <- NA
  n <- nrow(data)
  
  for (i in 1:n) {
    if (is.na(OrigTime)) {
      OrigTime <- data$DateTime[[i]]
      calls <- 0
    }
    calls = calls + 1
    if (data$Status[[i]] == "Answered" | difftime(data$DateTime[[i]],OrigTime,units='hours') > maxdelay | i==n) {
      row <- row + 1
      result[[row]] <- data.frame(OrigTime = OrigTime, LastTime = data$DateTime[[i]], calls = calls, Status = factor(data$Status[[i]],levels=c("Answered" ,"Abandoned" ,"Engaged","Unknown")), Successful = ifelse(data$Status[[i]]=="Answered",'Y','N')  )
      OrigTime <- NA
    }
  }
  dplyr::bind_rows(result)
}

df %>% arrange(UserID,DateTime) %>%
       split(.$UserID) %>%
       map(function(data) {CondCount(data,1) }) %>%
       bind_rows(.id="UserID")
```

Please see the 2 steps that I had written prior to my edit. This time around, the period is ***1 hour*** and ***not 5 hour***.

With @Waldi 's solution, here is when it works on my real df (I apologise for the colour coding that I have used, if by chance there are any colour-blind SO users):-

*Correct outcome*

[image]

and with @Waldi 's solution, it will give you this:-

[image]

which is correct! This is what I am aiming for. However, I want to illustrate two examples of what happens when I run this code, which gives the undesired outcome:-

*Incorrect Outcome 1*

[image]

which gives you this:-

[image]

This is incorrect. It should be two rows with one for each attempt (each with a final status of "Abandoned") and not one row, as the time difference between the last two rows is greater than 60 mins.

*Incorrect Outcome 2*

[image]

which gives you this:-

[image]

This is incorrect. It should be two rows with one for each attempt (first row with a status of "Engaged", second row with a status of "Answered").

I have to give massive credit to @Waldi because the solution works perfectly for answered calls. However, it does not take into consideration the other status types i.e. Abandoned and Engaged. It may be a case of not enough conditions being met for these two statuses. As always, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: could you `dput` the two last examples with errors : I think I corrected the code but would like to test it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `purrr` to split data by user, and use a simple for-loop function to implement the logic you're looking for :

```
library(purrr)

CondCount <- function(data,maxdelay){
  result <- list()
  row <- 0
  calls <- 0
  OrigTime <- NA
  n <- nrow(data)
  
  for (i in 1:n) {
    if (is.na(OrigTime)) {
      OrigTime <- data$DateTime[[i]]
      calls <- 0
    }
    calls = calls + 1
    if (difftime(data$DateTime[[i]],OrigTime,units='hours') > maxdelay) {
      row <- row + 1
      result[[row]] <- data.frame(OrigTime = OrigTime, LastTime = data$DateTime[[i-1]], calls = calls, Status = factor(data$Status[[i-1]],levels=c("Answered" ,"Abandoned" ,"Engaged")), Successful = ifelse(data$Status[[i]]=="Answered",'Y','N')  )
      OrigTime <- data$DateTime[[i]]
    } 
    if ((data$Status[[i]] !="Engaged") | i == n) {
      row <- row + 1
      result[[row]] <- data.frame(OrigTime = OrigTime, LastTime = data$DateTime[[i]], calls = calls, Status = factor(data$Status[[i]],levels=c("Answered" ,"Abandoned" ,"Engaged")), Successful = ifelse(data$Status[[i]]=="Answered",'Y','N')  )
      OrigTime <- NA
    }
  } 
  dplyr::bind_rows(result)
}



df %>% arrange(UserID,DateTime) %>%
  split(.$UserID) %>%
  map(function(data) {CondCount(data,5) }) %>%
  bind_rows(.id="UserID")

       UserID            OrigTime            LastTime calls    Status Successful
1  022098d3cf 2020-08-01 03:15:00 2020-08-01 03:15:00     1  Answered          Y
2  022098d3cf 2020-08-01 05:45:00 2020-08-01 05:45:00     1  Answered          Y
3  022098d3cf 2020-08-01 08:15:00 2020-08-01 08:15:00     1 Abandoned          N
4  022098d3cf 2020-08-01 10:45:00 2020-08-01 10:45:00     1  Answered          Y
5  022098d3cf 2020-08-01 13:15:00 2020-08-01 13:15:00     1 Abandoned          N
6  022098d3cf 2020-08-01 15:45:00 2020-08-01 15:45:00     1 Abandoned          N
7  022098d3cf 2020-08-01 18:15:00 2020-08-01 18:15:00     1 Abandoned          N
8  18f13c3972 2020-08-01 01:15:00 2020-08-01 03:45:00     2 Abandoned          N
9  18f13c3972 2020-08-01 06:15:00 2020-08-01 06:15:00     1  Answered          Y
10 18f13c3972 2020-08-01 08:45:00 2020-08-01 13:45:00     3  Answered          Y
```

If the loop needs to be very fast, it can easily be converted to [Rcpp](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html).

NB : for some reason, set.seed(123) doesn't seem to be enough to create reproducible results.

Comment: thank you so much for your solution, it worked a treat! I would have spent far too long to come up with my own solution that worked as well as this :) I will credit you the 50 bounty reputation points when it allows me in 21 hours or so!

Comment: I think I need to amend the code slightly. I changed from a 5 hour threshold to a 1 hour threshold. However, I noticed that in some entries, there had been a couple of days between calls made by each `UserID`. I think it continued to look for a `Status` that was `Answered` instead of creating a row for an "Attempt" if there wasn't another call made within 1 hour of the previous call.  This is what I got: `UserID           OrigTime            LastTime            calls Status  Successful 
084272a5e6  2018-01-17 22:57:48 2018-01-19 20:28:32 2 Answered             Y`

Comment: It turned out that the first call out of the 2 in my example above was "Engaged". So what I should have gotten was one row where the Status was Engaged & Successful == N, and the next row where the call was Answered & Successful == Y. I think I need an `else` statement in the code somewhere, but what it would look like is something I need help with @Waldi

Comment: @Robin, I'll have a look at it tonight (CET)

Comment: Thank you, look forward to seeing what you come up with :)

Comment: See my edit, a few conditions weren't tested enough... Let me know if it's now OK

Comment: Thank you for the edit, I think it is almost there. There is just one issue. It is not preserving the `UserID` variable and is instead replacing each UserID with 1,2,3... I will create an edit with my original question to show you the output,

Comment: the row number is 1,2,3,4,.. but UserID column should preserve the original ID as in the example above.

Comment: could you `dput(head(realdata$UserID,10))`?

Comment: the class is character

Comment: thanks, and could you `dput(head(realdata$UserID,10))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220927/discussion-between-robin-turkington-and-waldi).